# Generators for the intersection of two maximal ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I=\langle x-a,y-b \rangle$ and $J=\langle x-c,y-d \rangle$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$. ($I$ and $J$ are maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$).

> Is it true that $I \cap J = \langle (x-a)(x-c),(y-b)(y-d) \rangle$?

($I \cap J$ is a [radical](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Radical_ideal) ideal).

I see that $\langle (x-a)(x-c),(y-b)(y-d) \rangle \subseteq I \cap J$,
but I am not sure about the other direction.

**My proof:**

$\langle (x-a)(x-c),(y-b)(y-d) \rangle \subseteq I \cap J$:
An element $W$ on the left side is of the form $W= U(x-a)(x-c)+V(y-b)(y-d)$,
where $U,V \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Let $U_1=U(x-a), U_2=U(x-c), V_1=V(y-b), V_2=V(y-d)$.
Then,
$W=U_1(x-c)+V_1(y-d) \in J$ and $W=U_2(x-a)+V_2(y-b) \in I$,
so $W \in I \cap J$.

$I \cap J \subseteq \langle (x-a)(x-c),(y-b)(y-d) \rangle$:
An element $W$ on the left side is of the form $W=S_1(x-a)+T_1(y-b)$, where $S_1,T_1 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (since it belongs to $I$), and $W=S_2(x-c)+T_2(y-d)$ (since it belongs to $J$). 
Therefore, $W=S_1(x-a)+T_1(y-b)=S_2(x-c)+T_2(y-d)$;
why should $x-c$ divide $S_1$ and $y-d$ divide $T_1$?

A proof (or a counterexample) is welcome.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You have to assume that $a\ne c$ or $b\ne d$. In this case the ideals are comaximal, and then the intersection equals the product.

Comment: @user26857, thank you very much! Nice explanation. (If $a=c$ and $b=d$, then $I=J$, so $I \cap J = I \supsetneq \langle (x-a)^2, (y-b)^2 \rangle$).

Comment: I forgot to mention (but I think you figured this out) that your claim is wrong (even with the assumption from my first comment). The product of those maximal ideals is not necessary equal with what you wanted.

Comment: @user26857, thank you for the clarification. The generators of $IJ$ are $\{(x-a)(x-c),(x-a)(y-d),(y-b)(x-c),(y-b)(y-d)\}$?